# Can't make permalink of CPT work

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

i'm learning how to use wordpress, but i've encountered a big problem. I'm trying to create a custom post type, i've used this code:

```
add_action('init', 'init_realizzazioni');

function init_realizzazioni() {

$labels = array(
    'name'               => __('Realizzazioni'),
    'singular_name'      => __('Realizzazione'),
    'add_new'            => __('Aggiungi realizzazione'),
    'add_new_item'       => __('Nuova realizzazione'),
    'edit_item'          => __('Modifica realizzazione'),
    'new_item'           => __('Nuova realizzazione'),
    'all_items'          => __('Elenco Realizzazioni'),
    'view_item'          => __('Visualizza Realizzazione'),
    'search_items'       => __('Cerca Realizzazione'),
    'not_found'          => __('Realizzazione non trovato'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Realizzazione non trovata nel cestino'),
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels, 
    'public'             => true,    
    'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'realizzazioni'), 
    'has_archive'        => true, 
    'hierarchical'       => false, 
    'menu_position'      => 5, 
    'supports'           => array( 
                            'title',
                            'editor',
                            'thumbnail', 
                            'excerpt'
                            ),
);


   register_post_type('realizzazione', $args); 
}
```

and everything seems ok.. i can see the post type and create ne ones.

The problem is that i can't visualize a the archive page. I've set has_archive and rewrite in the right way.. i can't figure out because when i go to:

`localhost/wp/realizzazioni`
or
`localhost/wp/realizzazione`

it give me 404.

I've also tried to create an `archive-realizzazione.php` but it gives me 404 again.

here is the archive-realizzazione code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: realizzazione
 */


get_header(); ?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried flushing your rewrite rules by visiting the Permalinks Settings page and clicking on "Save Changes"?

Comment: yes, nothing happen!

Comment: When you create a new CPT post and click on View Post from the editing screen, do you see it, or do you get a 404?

Comment: Can you also rule out a theme or plugin issue by deactivating all plugins and activating Twenty Thirteen or Twenty Fourteen theme. I tried your code on my site and I have no issues.

Comment: @Patj with the single no post i have no problem.. it goes directly to : localhost/wp/?realizzazione=real2

Comment: @itrogers i've tried  to active 2014 theme but it gives me the same problem!

Comment: Please edit your post to include your archive-realizzazione.php code

Comment: @itrogers done. but it's a simple empty template file

Comment: @ciaoben can you confirm that it is in fact a 404 error? If the archive page is just showing up blank, that's because your archive-realizzazione.php is only calling the header and footer. Try removeing that php file from your theme and see if it works after that.

Comment: Your permalinks must be set to something other than default under Settings > Permalinks for this to work, it appears you have default permalinks. See [Using Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) in Codex.

Answer (score 0):

The `rewrite` value actually comes before your post slug, so you need to visit `localhost/wp/realizzazioni/{{POST_SLUG}}` to view the post. If your new post's name is "Test" you should be able to view the post at `localhost/wp/realizzazioni/test`.

Other tips: Make sure there isn't a *page* already using the `realizzazioni` slug. Finally, flush your permalinks by going to Settings->Permalinks and just click Save Changes without making any changes.